# Access HTML 5 Player - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, html, sdk, hpple

I am using Hpple to get links from webpages and have a problem. Because flash is unsupported on iOS, I have to use the HTML 5 player. What I am trying to do is access the player. If the website loads, and the user doesn't have flash, then there is an option to watch the video using the HTML 5 player. This is what the HTML looks like.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/viewvid.php?viewcode=VIEW_CODE" class="useHTML5"></a>
```

What I want to know is how would I access the HTML player using the iOS SDK? I've been trying forever.

Answer (score 0):

You link should load the player and you can use `<video>` tag to play videos.

```
<video src="http://example.com/path/mymovie.mov"
         controls
         height=340 width=640
         poster="http://example.com/path/poster.jpg">[enter link description here][1]
  </video>
```

For more details you can check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html